# What material Thor's clothes are made of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

When Thor opened the *Iris* of Nidavellir's forge, he got 3rd degree burns. The heat he was exposed to was able to melt Uru. And, yet, his clothes survived.

[image: Thor Opening Iris of Stormbreaker Forge]

How? Thor definitely doesn't have aura kind of protection like silver age Superman as observed from *Thor: Ragnarok* movie.

What material Thor's clothes are made of?

Comment: It's a rare-known material called "The-filmmakers-had-to-do-it-this-way-otherwise-you-would-have-had-a-bare-naked-man-in-an-otherwise-nudity-free-movie-just-accept-it-as-it-is-ium".

Comment: It's the same material as Captain Marvel's clothes.

Comment: It's to do with the ['MySuitIsAlsoSuper' Trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MySuitIsAlsoSuper)

Comment: The duplicate is looking for comic and MCU answers and his outfit likely only changed looks over the movies not materials. But even so any answer to this would be an answer to that.

Comment: In the comics, super costumes are made of unstable molecules, a substance invented by Reed Richards. They can stretch along with Mr Fantastic, turn invisible along with Invisible Girl, and they don't burn when the Human Torch flames on. Any time a costume isn't destroyed, just assume it's unstable molecules. links: 1) https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Unstable_Molecules / 2) https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Unstable_Molecules

Comment: ummm, ***Thorium?***

Comment: Literal plot armor.

Comment: @Shreedhar Neat!